# Why did the Tesseract "burn" a hole through Red Skull's plane but not Nick Fury's desk?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel, captain-america-the-first-avenger

In the end-credits scene of ***Captain Marvel***, the Tesseract was thrown up by Goose on Nick Fury's desk. I remembered the final fight scene in ***Captain America: The First Avenger*** where the Tesseract was dropped after the Skull was teleported to Vormir. It 'burned' through the metal walkway after dropping (or is it the floor? nor sure of the right term) on the ship, as seen [here](https://youtu.be/6l0PNsZjJRs?t=171):

However, why did it do not 'burn' through Fury's desk? It seems to be made of just wood, compared to the metal on Red Skull's ship. Is there some kind of special requirement so that it does not 'burn' through someone or something?

Comment: You see the Tesseract multiple times being held in briefcases, and can be picked up by your hand.  It 'burning' like that is more unusual than not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This Tesseract in Captain Marvel was stable and wasn't overreacting.

However, it was overloaded in The First Avenger, that's why it burned a hole through the metal aircraft. When Red Skull and Captain America fight in the plane, they broke the hydra-built machine holding tesseract. It was already reacting in that machine and breaking it caused it to overreact and melt. After that Red Skull holds it with his bare hands while it was overreacting so it sent him to the other world.

Whereas in Captain Marvel, it was not the case. Tesseract was in its normal state. Even Nick Fury holds it with his hands.

Comment: Yes, they broke the machine and Red Skull **used** the tesseract.

Comment: Is that how the Tesseract is supposed to work? I'm unfamiliar with the comics and I'm not sure how much they adapted in the movie. So the Tesseract 'overloads' when it is used? Do the experiments done by the Hydra not qualify as 'use'?

Comment: It was already burning in the machine built by Hydra and breaking the machinery caused it to overreact. I've removed the word "use" as it was creating confusion.

Comment: How does overloading a power stone work exactly? I thought it is potentially an unlimited source of power. And it seems to have a will of its own. So, it can, technically, prevent overloading itself, right? 'When the power used to harness its energy is cut off, the Tesseract turns the power back on.' This was noted by Selvig in Avengers.

Comment: 'It was already burning in the machine built by Hydra...' If it was, how come the machinery did not break? Does this mean that Hydra was able to create a container that the Tesseract cannot burn through?

Comment: @I.Am If it has a will of its own, maybe it *chose not* to stop itself from overloading, in order to escape its current situation.  Heck, maybe it chose to *begin* overloading in the first place.

Comment: If it has a will, perhaps the Tesseract objected to being used in a machine.  It wasn't overloading. It was hopping mad.

Comment: The tesseract, by which I mean the space stone, almost certainly does have a will of its own.  How else does it conveniently transport the Red Skull to Vormir so he can serve as the guide to the soul stone?  That's not random coincidence, that's willful action.  That's putting a plan into action.

Comment: What do you mean by "overreacting"?

Answer (score 1):

In the *Captain America* scene the Tesseract is handled while it is active and powering the plane. Even more energy is presumably required to then transport Red Skull to Vormir (we don't know whether he consciously triggers this, or if it's just something that happens if you don't know what you're doing and pick it up while it's active). It must have deactivated shortly afterwards otherwise it would've continued burning through the seafloor and been unrecoverable (or been a lot easier to find due to the massive plumes of steam).

In the *Captain Marvel* scene the Tesseract is inactive, so nothing in particular happens.

Comment: Red Skull says in IW that the Tesseract "cast [him] out", so he probably didn't intentionally trigger that reaction.

Comment: @DaniellYancey I was considering the possibility that he had the general desire to “be somewhere else”, which triggered it.